# Need help to understand branch cuts

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I have a question about branch cuts. Suppose you have $f(z) =  \sqrt{z^2 -1} $. Then the branch points are $ \pm 1$, so we can make a branch cut from $ (- \infty , 1]$ in order to define $f$ continuously. Do we also say that $f$ has a branch point at $ \infty$? Isn't so that a branch cut need to be taken between two branch points or have I misunderstood?

Another thing, if $p(x) $ is a polynomial, and $f(z) = \sqrt{p(z)} $ is it true the the branch points of $f$ is the same as the zeros of the polynomials? If not, what is the connection?

Thanks

Comment: If you cut along $(-\infty,\,1]$, you cut along $[-1,\,1]$ and then just remove some further points.

Comment: OK. So, what you say is that branch cuts can always be taken between two branch points? You don't need to include $ \infty$ ?

Comment: For the "other thing", consider $p(z) = z^2$, $p(z) = z^4$ to see that not all zeros are branch points. What is the condition for a zero of $p$ to be a branch point? And generally, $\infty$ is a candidate for a branch point too.

Comment: So if $p(z) = z^k$ for $k$ odd then $f(z) = \sqrt{p(z)} $ has a branch point at zero, or if $p(z) = q(z)^k$ for $k$ even with $q$ being a polynomial then the zeros are not branch point. But otherwise they are branch points?

Comment: Sometimes you need more than two (consider a cube root). The "jumps" across the cut at the connected branch points must annihilate.

Comment: For the square root, if the order of the zero $\zeta$ is even ($2k$), it's not a branch point, the two branches of the square root then are different sheets of the covering around $\zeta$. If $z$ winds around $\zeta$ once, $p(z)$ winds around $0$ $2k$ times, and $\sqrt{p(z)}$ $k$ times. If the order is odd ($2k+1$), $\sqrt{p(z)}$ winds around zero $k+\frac12$ times.

Comment: Yeah, I got it! Thanks. Could you explain why $ \infty $ is a candidate for a branch point ?

Comment: $\sqrt{z^3}$. $\infty$ is as exceptional a point as $0$, more generally, if you have $\sqrt{g(z)}$ for a meromorphic function $g$, poles and zeros can be branch points.